# Authorize.Net API not responding

Tags: codeigniter-3, authorize.net

Suddenly my code which I was using from last couple of years now started throwing error. I am using codeigniter php framework.

Could not figure out what is happening.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: AuthorizeNetTD_Response::$xpath_xml

Filename: shared/AuthorizeNetXMLResponse.php

Line Number: 54

Backtrace:

File: /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/application/lib/shared/AuthorizeNetXMLResponse.php
Line: 54
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/application/controllers/Collectionupdate.php
Line: 258
Function: xpath

File: /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Common.php on line 658 and defined in /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown in /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 190
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Common.php on line 658 and defined in /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 /home/directpr/public_html/reports/new/system/core/Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown

Filename: core/Exceptions.php

Line Number: 190

Backtrace:
```

Comment: There's no way to help you without seeing the code throwing these errors

Comment: let me paste that here

Comment: /**
     * Run an xpath query on the cleaned XML response
     *
     * @ param  string $path
     * @return array  Returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error.
     */
    public function xpath($path)
    {
        return $this->xpath_xml->xpath($path);
    }
This is where the error is created

Comment: Can you add that to your question instead of making it a comment?

Comment: We're having a very similar issue here, not using codeigniter, but with a PHP client. I strongly suspect that Authorize.net has changed something in the API that requires a code update for the Authorize.net API client library.

Comment: If you go to `const LIVE_URL = "https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api";` with just a simple HTTP GET, it returns JSON:
`{"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00003","text":"Root element is missing."}]}}`
and the API code that I have seems to check `this->resultCode` rather than checking in a messages submember.  This kinda implies they changed the result format, although I'm not really familiar with the Authorize API, just trying to figure out why our longstanding working code has suddenly become broken.

Comment: Got this resolved...It was an issue from Authorize and as a solution we just need to change the URL to https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved. It was an issue from Authorize and as a solution we have changed the Live URL to https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api